# Relative number of post in category

Tags: posts, categories

For a post x in a category y, how can the following output be achieved:

- Post x is the `n`th out of `m` posts in the category y.

where `m` is the total number of posts in the category, and `n` is the number of the current post (ordered by publishing date).

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the main query or a custom WP_Query for displaying the posts?

If so :

```
 $wp_query->found_posts; //Main query
 $wp_query->current_post; // current post index
```

or

```
 $my_wp_query->found_posts; //custom wp_query object - total found posts
 $my_wp_query->current_post; // current post index
```

**So, example**

```
 if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 ?>
      <p>The post <?php the_title(); ?> is <?php echo $wp_query->current_post; ?>th of <?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?> in category <?php echo 'your cat here'; ?></p>

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the "th", here's how to use the proper ordinal suffix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109978/php-display-number-with-ordinal-suffix

Comment: @Geert +1 - I only give rough examples, but that link will surely come in handy.

Comment: It's for a single post page.